# JQuery selector running time

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

How does JQuery selector works internally? Is it a js `getElementById` kind of function? What's the running time in order to fetch an object from the DOM?

For example:

```
<html>
  <div class='container'>
      <div id='myID'> 
         <p class="myText">My Text</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

And this JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myID").click(function(){
       $("myText").hide(); //Running time?
   });
});
```

Comment: See for yourself: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=init

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of getting execution time, first is [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd)(only for debugging), second is [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Difference between `Date.now()` and `performance.now()` - date.now rounds to milliseconds, perf.now to microseconds

```js
//This will console.log the result
$(document).ready(function(){
   var myTimerName = 'myTimer1';
   $("#myID").click(function(){
       console.time(myTimerName);
       $(".myText").hide(function(){
           console.timeEnd(myTimerName);
       });
   });
});

//If you need to export this time, use window.performance.now()
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myID").click(function(){
       var start = performance.now();
       $(".myText").hide(function(){
           var end = performance.now();
           $('#timer').text((end - start) + 'ms');
       });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <div class='container'>
      <div id='myID'> 
         <p class="myText">My Text</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
</html>
```